# Getting the value of Input and inserting the value to <td>

Tags: jquery, html

When I press the button, the data from the `input` is not transferring inside the `<td>`. The (tabios) name must change based on the value of the input, I have included the snippet here in my post. Thank for the answers and comments in advance

```js
$('buttonnext').click(function() {
  // var date_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
  var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();

  $('#datalastname').val(lastname);
  $('#datafirstname').val(firstname);
  $('#dataemail').val(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br> 
Lastname <input type="text" name="" style="width: 250px;" id="lastname"><br><br> 
Firstname <input type="text" name="" style="width: 250px;" id="firstname"><br><br> 
Email <input type="text" name="" style="width: 250px;" id="email"><br><br>
<button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 250px;" class="buttonnext">Next</button><br><br>

<table class="table table-bordered" style="border-style: solid;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lastname</td>
      <td id="datalastname">Tabios</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Firstname</td>
      <td id="datafirstname">Jimmy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td id="dataemail">Johndoe@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to change the (Tabios) last name value using the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it's working.
To change the text of  you could use `$('#datalastname').text(lastname);`
Also 
`<button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 250px;" class="buttonnext">Next</button><br><br>`

Above code contains 2 `class=""` tags.

```js
$('.buttonnext').click(function() {
  // var date_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
  var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();

  $('#datalastname').text(lastname);
  $('#datafirstname').text(firstname);
  $('#dataemail').text(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br> 
Lastname <input type="text" name="" style="width: 250px;" id="lastname"><br><br> 
Firstname <input type="text" name="" style="width: 250px;" id="firstname"><br><br> 
Email <input type="text" name="" style="width: 250px;" id="email"><br><br>
<button class="btn btn-success buttonnext" style="width: 250px;">Next</button><br><br>

<table class="table table-bordered" style="border-style: solid;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lastname</td>
      <td id="datalastname">Tabios</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Firstname</td>
      <td id="datafirstname">Jimmy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td id="dataemail">Johndoe@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh I see, I put 2 classes inside the button, Thank you so much :) this helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add dot as it is class. To select elements with a specific class, write a period (`.`) character, followed by the name of the class, so the selector will be `$('.buttonnext')`

```js
$('.buttonnext').click(function() {
  // var date_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
  var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();

  $('#datalastname').val(lastname);
  $('#datafirstname').val(firstname);
  $('#dataemail').val(email);
});
```

Comment: Still the same problem, the value is not triggering inside the <td>, even I add a dot into the buttontext

Answer (score 0):

to replace the td text use text() instead of val().check the updated code::

```js
$('.buttonnext').click(function() {
  // var date_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
  var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();

  $('#datalastname').text(lastname);
  $('#datafirstname').text(firstname);
  $('#dataemail').text(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br> 
Lastname <input type="text" name="" style="width: 250px;" id="lastname"><br><br> 
Firstname <input type="text" name="" style="width: 250px;" id="firstname"><br><br> 
Email <input type="text" name="" style="width: 250px;" id="email"><br><br>
<button class="btn btn-success buttonnext" style="width: 250px;">Next</button><br><br>

<table class="table table-bordered" style="border-style: solid;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lastname</td>
      <td id="datalastname">Tabios</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Firstname</td>
      <td id="datafirstname">Jimmy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td id="dataemail">Johndoe@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Still the same problem, the value is not triggering inside the <td>

Comment: check the snippet or fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/qfLdmtau

both are working